# Automating the execution of a Jupyter notebook in Azure

Tags: azure, automation, jupyter-notebook, virtual-machine, jupyterhub

I have a script in the Jupyter notebook, which creates interactive graphs for the data set that it is provided. I then convert the output as an HTML file without inputs to create a report for that dataset to be shared with my colleagues.
I have also used papermill to parametrize the process, that I send it the name of the file and it creates a report for me. All the datasets are stored in Azure datalake.

Now it is all very easy when I am doing it in my local machine, but I want to automate the process to generate reports for the new incoming datasets every hour and store the HTML outputs in the azure datalake, I want to run this automation on the cloud.

I initially began with using automation accounts, but I didnot know how to execute a jupyter notebook in the automation accounts, and where to store my .ipynb file. I have also looked at the jupyter hub server (VM) on azure cloud but I am unable to understand how to automate it as well.

Can any one help me with a way to automate the entire process on the Azure Cloud in the cheapest way possible, because I have to generate a lot of reports.

Thanks!

Comment: azure has tools for setting up papermill workflows out of the box: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/notebooks/parameterize-papermill?view=sql-server-ver15. if you're looking for a DIY setup (cheaper and harder) that's way too large a scope for a stack overflow question. good luck!

Comment: Thanks @MichaelDelgado, I have already looked that the azure datastudio and notebooks, but I am confused how can I run it in the azure cloud, like automate it using automation accounts or functions triggered by time That is what I am unable to structure. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from Automation, you can use **Azure Functions** as mentioned in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/example-scenario/data/automating-diagnostic-jupyter-notebook#alternatives):

· To run a PowerShell-based Jupyter Notebook, you can use PowerShell in an Azure function to call the [Invoke-ExecuteNotebook](https://github.com/dfinke/PowerShellNotebook#executing-a-notebook) cmdlet. This is similar to the technique described above for Automation jobs. For more information, see [Azure Functions PowerShell developer guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-powershell).

· To run a SQL-based Jupyter Notebook, you can use PowerShell in an Azure function to call the [Invoke-SqlNotebook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlnotebook?view=sqlserver-ps) cmdlet. For more information, see [Azure Functions PowerShell developer guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-powershell).

· To run a Python-based Jupyter Notebook, you can use Python in an Azure function to call papermill. For more information, see [Azure Functions Python developer guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python).

References: [Run Jupyter Notebook on the Cloud in 15 mins #Azure | by Anish Mahapatra | Towards Data Science](https://towardsdatascience.com/running-jupyter-notebook-on-the-cloud-in-15-mins-azure-79b7797e4ef6), [How to run a Jupyter notebook with Python code automatically on a daily basis? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48750055/how-to-run-a-jupyter-notebook-with-python-code-automatically-on-a-daily-basis) and [Scheduled execution of Python script on Azure - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59571247/scheduled-execution-of-python-script-on-azure)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! I will try it out.

Comment: Please do not forget to "Accept the answer” and “up-vote” wherever the information provided helps you, this can be beneficial to other community members.